# QGIS Atlas map composition to show only points inside Polygon?

Tags: qgis, atlas, rule-based

I want to create an atlas map where I have some 40 polygons, 100 points and 200 lines as different shapefile. Now I want to automate the atlas map preparation for each polygon and needs to show the points and lines which is falling inside of the polygon.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An other way. I don't comment image. 
If you need more, just ask.

1. Example: Initial situation

[image]

2.Polygon layer properties (optional)

[image]
[image]

3. Point layer properties

[image]
[image]

4. Line layer properties. 2 possibility: "Within" or "Intersects"

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Dhananjayan - You're welcome. if it answers your question, you can click to rate the answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

I guess that polygon's layer are going to define your atlas, so I made an example based on that.

1. Join attributes of the atlas layer with those objects (points and lines) that are inside. It should be something like this (I just did an example with points):
   [image]
2. Go to properties/simbology and select rule-based and edit it like this image. It means that just those points that belongs to their atlas page are going to be shown. 
   [image]
3. Las step is to generate the atlas selecting the joined attribute as page name. 
   [image]

There are other ways but I think that this here is preaty easy to do it. Do the same with lines or other layers.