# qgis atlas: represent only polygons that are within the main polygon

Tags: qgis-3, atlas

In the following image, the polygon without filling and the polygon with the red filling are two different layers. In my atlas I would like that only those red Polygons are represented that are inside the polygons with no filling.

[image]

The atlas is iterating over the polygons with no filling.

Comment: Short way : inverted symbology on black & white polygons, it will mask exterior polygons. Long way : black & white polygon `ID` in red polygons and create a rule symbology with the `@atlas_featureid`.

Answer (score 0):

This link I haven't seen before solved the Problem perfectly.

[QGIS Atlas map composition to show only points inside Polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295385/qgis-atlas-map-composition-to-show-only-points-inside-polygon?rq=1)